# Google Sheets Average of Each Row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average, array-formulas

This formula gives a single average result from the whole range, also is not dynamic.

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER($B:$E,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW($B:$E)>COUNT($B:$E))))
```

What I need from the formula is to:

- Calculate 1 average result per row, from the second row downwards.
- Count only the first 4 cells with values in the row, ignoring blank cells.

[image: Example]

[Demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fSwFWuAIBW5gZj2yFAc-eD--iMFQhrQDFz2IEZCIBFY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please remember in the future, sharing a sample sheet, in addition to an image, saves people having to re-enter your data, to test out their solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @kirkg13: can you show us  the expected outcome? Just to make sure we understood correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in B4:

```
=query(transpose(query(transpose(C4:H), 
 "select "&textjoin(",", 1, ArrayFormula(if(len(A4:A),
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A4:A)-ROW(A4)+1&")", )))&"")), 
 "select Col2")
```

Comment: Found a problem with your formula in some instances. If there's a value in column A but none in the same row from C onwards then the formula doesn't work. Added a demo sheet. Let me know if you think is better to open a new question to discuss further the frmula.

Comment: @Preack fixed. see your sheet

Comment: You are the blasting Boss.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler option, must be copied down:

```
=AVERAGE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN((FILTER(C2:2,ISNUMBER(C2:2))),1,4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?
Try this formula in B4, and drag down.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
             QUERY({TRANSPOSE(C4:H4)},"select Col1 where Col1 >0 limit 4",0),
             "select sum(Col1)/count(Col1) where Col1>0 label sum(Col1)/count(Col1) ''",0))
```

Let us know of any issues.
I'll add some explanation if this seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

new alternative:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/BYROW(OFFSET(C2,,,
 MAX((INDIRECT("C2:"&ROWS(C:C))<>"")*ROW(C2:C)), 6), 
 LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))))
```

[image]

see more at: [ArrayFormula of Average on Infinite Truly Dynamic Range in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65435313/5632629)