# Google Sheets sum(max) in row

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

Is it possible to sum the biggest values of each row?
This will be more clear: [image: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ah97AwIhZt1RcxS2FMkEmKfwIKbnhMQsXyESzesSI4/edit?usp=sharing]

The goal is to move actions from `MAX(C1; C2)` and `SUM(MAX)` to one query;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

impossible, or is it...

if you got only two columns as in your example you can do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(C7:C>D7:D; C7:C; D7:D))
```

[image]

for multiple columns you can find the formula here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435321/5632629

(just change avg for max)