# How to average values from specific cells which are not empty and not zero?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table for conducting my family budget. I would like to have a function that shows average for specific cells like this

```
=AVERAGE(F11;M11;S11;Y11;AE11;AK11;AQ11;AW11;BC11;BI11;BO11;BU11)
```

but it should not consider EMPTY or "0" cells. I get zeroes when I pre-create a table with `=sum(A4:A7)` which returns ZERO.

This means that I need to see average for expenses that I make but only for months that are valid.

Please help, I am exhausted without finding an answer.

Table looks like this:

[image: Family budget example]

[image: div0 error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(A1:C1; A1:C1; "<>"; A1:C1; "<>0"))
```

[image]

also, to not get 0 by sum you can do:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(A4:A7)))
```

Comment: Can you please also advise, how can I not have an div/0! error for lines where I have empty cells and average is calculated? Thank you in advance! At the moment I use =AVERAGE(F14;M14;T14;AA14;AH14;AO14;AV14;BC14;BJ14;BQ14;BX14;CE14) because I need to omit cells which are between these, as they contain info by weeks which is already summed up...

Comment: wrapping it into IFERROR should do the trick

Comment: @SufficientHappiness if you feel like you are ready to level up, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435321/5632629

Comment: documentation for the sake of completeness: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534 and https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304

Comment: Thank you guys! @player0, I checked your link - it is very cool what formulas can do. However I can't understand it yet.