# JOIN header row values across a row based on non-blank values in cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So I have two rows:

| ID | TagDog | TagCat | TagChair | TagArm | Grouped Tags (need help with this) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | TRUE |  | TRUE | ***TagDog,TagArm*** |

Row 1 consists mainly of Tags, while rows 2+ are entries. This data ties ENTRIES to TAGS.

What I'm needing to do is concatenate/join the tag names per entry. For example, look at the last column above.

I suspect we could write a formula that would:

- Create an array of non-empty cells in the row. (IE: [2,4])
- Return it with the header row `A` (IE: [A2,A4])
- Then `join` them together by a comma

But I am unsure how to write the formula, or if this is even the best approach.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm whether my understanding of your goal is correct. In your table, when the cell of `TagDog,TagArm` is "F2", the sample formula of `=JOIN(",",FILTER($B$1:$E$1,B2:E2=TRUE))` is the result you expect? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the formula:

```
={
  "Grouped Tags (need help with this)";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(
      TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
        IF(NOT(B2:E11),, B1:E1)
      ),, COLUMNS(B1:E1)))
    ), "\s+", ",")
  )
}
```

[image]

The trick used is called **vertical query smash**. That's the part:

```
TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(...),, Nnumber_of_columns))
```

You can find a brief description of this one and his friends [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435321/279806).

Comment: Incredible! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to create a single formula that would do this for me, so instead, I utilized a formula inside of Sheets' Find/Replace tool, and it worked like a charm!

I did a find/replace, replacing all instances of `TRUE` with the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),3),"$","")&"$1")
```

What this formula does is it finds the cell's letter, then gets the first row of the cell using `INDIRECT`.

Breaking down the formula:

- `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())` returns the direct reference: `$H$1`
- `LEFT("$H$1",3)` returns `$H$`
- `SUBSTITUBE("$H$","$","")` replaces the dollar signs ($) and returns `H`
- `INDIRECT(H&"$1")` references the exact cell `H$1`

Now, I can replace all instances of `TRUE` with that formula and the magic happens!

Here is a video explanation: https://youtu.be/SXXlv4JHDA8

Hopefully, that helps someone -- however, I would still be interested in seeing what the formula is for this solution.

Comment: There is another approach if it is ok to copy the formula down: `=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(B2:E2),, $B$1:$E$1)))` ([screen](https://i.imgur.com/KEgb40U.png))

Comment: And in find and replace you could replace it with `=OFFSET(A1, 0, COLUMN() - 1, 1, 1)`