# Concatenate Use in Google Sheets (Not in MS-Excel)

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to ask about how to use concatenation formula in Google Sheets (Not in MS-Excel). In Specific, I'd like to Combine Multiple values in Columns to a single value in 1 row. Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions.

Thanks in Advance mates,
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

depends...

you can mostly use just `&`

```
=A1&B1
```

---

```
=INDEX(A1:A5&B1:B5&C1:C5)
```

if you need something advanced try query smash

```
=QUERY(A:D;; 9^9)      << this will collapse all rows of each column into one row
```

for more about query smash see: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435321/5632629**