# Google Sheets =QUERY( ) Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

How does the "`=QUERY()`" function work in Google Sheets, i.e. what does it do? I have read [this post](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB), but still don't fully understand...

Answer (score 1):

QUERY is something like FILTER on steroids because it can aggregate (sum, count, min, max, avg) stuff and also pivot stuff grouping the dataset eg. mimicking UNIQUE. also as the only function there it can understand strings/text input as commands for example:

A1: `2+3`

A2: `=QUERY(, "select "&A1)`

QUERY is also able to understand the concept of header rows. and lastly, we can abuse QUERY to concatenate stuff in any direction because JOIN and TEXTJOIN does now work under ARRAYFORMULA

see more QUERY magic at: [stackoverflow.com/q/65435313](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65435313/5632629)