# How to simplify "IS NOT NULL" for multiple columns when using QUERY function in Google Sheets?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I have this formula:

```
=QUERY(
    {AG4:AW101},
    "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17 
    where Col1 is not null
    and Col1 is not null
    and Col2 is not null
    and Col3 is not null
    and Col4 is not null
    and Col5 is not null
    and Col6 is not null
    and Col7 is not null
    and Col8 is not null
    and Col9 is not null
    and Col10 is not null
    and Col11 is not null
    and Col12 is not null
    and Col13 is not null
    and Col14 is not null
    and Col15 is not null
    and Col16 is not null
    and Col17 is not null
    order by Col"&$N$1&" "&$N$2&"")
```

Is there anyway to make it shorter? Do I really need to repeat `and ColX is not null` for every column?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The query looks very readable. You can get it shorter by removing `and Col1 is not null` :-D And you could concatenate the columns or add them up if they are numeric and then check the result for null, but this would make the query less readable and may also slow it down.

Comment: You mean like player0 wrote down below? You think his solution is less readable? Or were you thinking of something else?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `where col1 + col2 + ... is not null`. I consider this less readable, and as mentioned it could slow down the query immensely. And yes, player0's answer may be clever, but I consider the query very bad in terms of readability (and thus maintainability).

Comment: Do you consider their query readable? Would you know at a quick glance what it's about? It is very easy with your original query, and I doubt you'll find any as readable as yours.

Comment: You're right about readibility. But I am going to try to understand how he did it and thus will become readable I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join them. lets say your range is A:F and you want to check B:F for `is not null`, then try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:F, TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F),,9^9)))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6
  where Col7 is not null", ))
```

Comment: I don't know how that works but it works even better than mine because for some reason my formula was hiding some rows and yours is not. Would you mind explaining a bit more the logic behind this?

Comment: @Verminous A:F equals to Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6. then Col7 is made by joining columns B:F into one single column which is achieved by TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F),,9^9))). if you want to run it separately to see what's going on try: `=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F),,9^9))))` more on this query smash can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435321/5632629