# Google Sheets: Merge two tables (arrays) with many to many relationship

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have 2 tables (arrays) in Google Sheets, that they have a **related column**. And I need to **join** these tables.
What I need is get a result being that the two tables have a **many-to-many** relationship.

[**Example sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UoJiVkm1yRKhHWxI8YPd-47tGv5GFkYdx3Ph_N9KsN4/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: tables with many to many relationship]

In this example, I have two tables (A:C and E:G). I need a result like table I:N.

Table A:C -> I have players and how much them has completed certain game. (key: 'player'+'game')

Table E:G -> I have groups that each one has different goals for some games. (key: 'group'+'game')

I need a **result** that column 'game' is the related column of each table.

**Note that**: 
row 15 of first table: (`d - b6 - 55%`), and 
row 7 of second table: (`k7 - b7 - 60%`), 
have no relation, so they aren't on third table.

I've tried to combine some formulas like `ARRAYFORMULA`, `VLOOKUP`, `FILTER`, `INDEX`, `OFFSET`...
But I hadn't success with none of them.

---

I've found a solution with script [`SUPERSQL()`](https://youtu.be/93JfUPdnLhE) Function, but I wouldn't like to use scripts, just formulas.

Comment: Done! 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UoJiVkm1yRKhHWxI8YPd-47tGv5GFkYdx3Ph_N9KsN4/edit?usp=sharing

I have two tables on the ranges: 'A:C' and 'E:G'.
I desire get 'I:N' with formulas, at this example I filled up manually.

Comment: Your best option is `SUPERSQL` but you wouldn't like to use scripts.

Comment: My problem using `SUPERSQL` is because my other scripts stop working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to place one key column vertically as it is, and another one horizontally (`TRANSPOSE()`).

Outside `QUERY` is just for rearranging columns and sorting.

More on `TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(...)))` and such is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435321/279806).

**Solution:**

```
=QUERY(
  {
    A1:C1\ E1:G1;
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      SPLIT(
        REGEXREPLACE(
          QUERY(
            FLATTEN(
              IF(
                FILTER(B2:B; B2:B <> "") <> TRANSPOSE(FILTER(F2:F; F2:F <> ""));;
                    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:C & "@"; B2:B <> ""));; COLUMNS(A2:C))) & " "
                  & QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E2:G & "@"; F2:F <> ""));; COLUMNS(E2:G))
              )
            );
            "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL";
          );
          "@$";
        );
        "@ ";
      )
    )
  };
  "SELECT Col4, Col1, Col2, Col6, Col3
   ORDER BY Col4, Col1, Col2";
  1
)
```

[image]